# How to filter out the result to get only file names in output result linux in c++98

Tags: c++, linux, string, vector, absolute-path

The current code snippet will match the pattern and list out all matching pattern files present in directory specified where in *below example **File*** is the pattern to be matched*, here the output will be listed with absolute path like below.

```
    /home/downloads/File1
    /home/downloads/File2
    /home/downloads/File3
    /home/downloads/File4
```

wherein, I am looking for only Filename to be listed, i,e like given below:

```
File1
File2
File3
File4
```

c++ code below:

```
    #include <glob.h>
    #include <cerrno>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdexcept>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;
    vector<string> glob(const string& pattern) {
        glob_t glob_result = {0}; // zero initialize
        // do the glob operation
        int return_value = ::glob(pattern.c_str(), GLOB_TILDE, NULL, &glob_result);
        if(return_value != 0) throw runtime_error(strerror(errno));
        // collect all the filenames into a std::vector<std::string>
        // using the vector constructor that takes two iterators
        vector<string> filenames(
            glob_result.gl_pathv, glob_result.gl_pathv + glob_result.gl_pathc);
        // cleanup
        globfree(&glob_result);
        
        // done
        return filenames;
    }
    int main() {
        try { // catch exceptions
               vector<string> res = glob("/home/downloads/File*"); // files with an "File" in the filename
               for(size_t i = 0; i< res.size(); ++i)
                  std::cout << res[i] << '\n';
            } catch(const exception& ex) {
            cerr << ex.what() << endl;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of, you can filter out directories. Change `GLOB_TILDE` with `GLOB_TILDE | GLOB_MARK` like this:

```
vector<string> glob(const string& pattern) {
    glob_t glob_result = {};
    vector<string> filenames;
    try {
        int return_value = ::glob(pattern.c_str(), GLOB_TILDE | GLOB_MARK, NULL, &glob_result);
        if (return_value != 0) {
            throw runtime_error(strerror(errno));
        }
        filenames.reserve(glob_result.gl_pathc);
        for (size_t globIndex = 0; globIndex < glob_result.gl_pathc; ++globIndex) {
            std::string filename = glob_result.gl_pathv[globIndex];
            if (filename.size() > 0 && filename[filename.size() - 1] != '/') {
                filenames.push_back(filename);
            }
        }
    } catch(...) {
        globfree(&glob_result);
        throw;
    }
    // cleanup
    globfree(&glob_result);

    // done
    filenames.shrink_to_fit();
    return filenames;
}
```

Notes:

- you will still have to `stat` every result and check if it is a file. Can be a symlink, a device file, a named pipe (FIFO)...
- the code was not exception safe, while filling the vector the memory may run out and your cleanup won't happen. Use try/catch or something like [scope_exit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_exit) (if you can) or write a guard object and use it's destructor.
- I am not sure should you `globfree` in case of error but valgrind suggests it is not a problem.